# How access to kubernetes with root user?

Tags: kubernetes

I am using bitnami/rabbitmq image in kubernetes pod. Seems the image don`t have a root. May I know how to add the root user in the kubernetes.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  The PNG file suggests you're trying to use a `kubectl exec` debugging shell to apply an insecure configuration to a single replica of your RabbitMQ broker; that won't survive the pod being deleted and recreated and won't propagate to other replicas, and it's probably not the right approach.  (Please avoid attaching screen shots of terminal windows to your questions; instead include the actual source code and error messages as plain text.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `3.7.7-r19` the RabbitMQ container has been migrated to a **non-root user approach**. Previously the container ran as the root user and the RabbitMQ daemon was started as the rabbitmq user. From now on, both the container and the RabbitMQ daemon run as user 1001. As a consequence, the data directory must be writable by that user. You can revert this behavior by changing USER 1001 to USER root in the Dockerfile.

So either you need to build **custom docker image** or use **old docker image**.

**Reference:**

https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/rabbitmq

https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/rabbitmq/README.md